# how to send a 302 redirect in a request handler of a nginx module?

Tags: redirect, cookies, nginx, module

I am appreciate any help I can get on the following issues.

I am trying to setup a cookie mapping server using nginx module.

In this case, I get a request like 'http://cms.mydomain.com/pixel.gif', and do the following

1. generate cookie id of mydomain
2. send a 302 redirect to browser like 'cms.otherdomain.com/pixel.gif?cookie_id=xxxx'
3. then other domain's cms redirect this request back, i'll get both cookie id and record the mapping.

and now I wonder what to do to send a 302 redirect back to browser, in a nginx request handle, deal with a **ngx_http_request_t *r** ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build your url into a variable  **rs**, then set it into nginx r->headers_out.location likes this:

```
    r->headers_out.location = ngx_list_push(&r->headers_out.headers);
    if (r->headers_out.location == NULL) {
        ngx_http_finalize_request(r, NGX_HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    r->headers_out.location->hash = 1;
    r->headers_out.location->key.len = sizeof("Location") - 1;
    r->headers_out.location->key.data = (u_char *) "Location";
    r->headers_out.location->value.len = r->uri.len + r->args.len + 2; 
    r->headers_out.location->value.data = (u_char *) rs; 
    return NGX_HTTP_MOVED_TEMPORARILY;
```

Comment: Can I add this in response body filter